# CSS drop-down menu hides under Flash (only) in Google Chrome.

Tags: html, css, flash, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I am having a problem with my CSS drop-down menu hiding under a Flash object. I've read that it isn't a matter of adjusting the z-index, rather the Flash itself. Fair enough..

I've also read that setting the "wmode" parameter to "transparent" should fix everything. It kind of works - the menu works in IE and Firefox, but not in Chrome. It still disappears under the Flash.

My code can be viewed at http://www.foolesweb.com/drafts/GreatShieldStore/index.html

Any help would be appreciated - none of the forums I've visited seem to have this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a `z-index:1` on the `ul` that is the drop down menu.

Also, you havent set a parameter on the object inside the object:

```
<object data="flash/store_slideshow.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="888" height="601">
        <param name="movie" value="flash/store_slideshow.swf">
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
        </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
```

Comment: I tried 'z-index' on every 'ul' in the drop-down, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: is it positioned relative/absolute?

Comment: Adding `wmode=transparent` to the object made it work for me. Seems like that was the issue.

Comment: Thank you rickyduck and paulGraffix! I wasn't looking closely at the conditional comments targeting non-IE browsers; instead I thought that code was for IE only.
And the wmode set to transparent worked..